# Copy content from one MYSQL table to another

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have two tables, tableA has multiple rows and contains data and tableB has only 2 rows and is empty.

```
tableA

id |  name   |  lastname  |  age
--------------------------------
1  |  John   |  Doe       |  40 
2  |  Paul   |  Miller    |  26 
3  |  Mary   |  Brown     |  32 


tableB

id |  fullname  
--------------
   Empty
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to have a query string to copy the ids and concatenate the name and last name and copy into tableB.

Expected result:

```
tableB

id |  fullname  
--------------
1  |  John Doe
2  |  Paul Miller
3  |  Mary Brown
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` query. Use the `CONCAT()` function to concatenate `name` and `lastname`.

Comment: The CONCAT() part I got it. The problem is using insert and select like this `INSERT INTO tableB (id, fulname) VALUES ( (SELECT id...), CONCAT( (SELECT....), ' ', (SELECT...) ) )` throws the exception 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `VALUES` when you're inserting from a `SELECT` query.

```
INSERT INTO TableB (id, fullname)
SELECT id, CONCAT(name, ' ', lastname)
FROM TableA
```